# How to properly get message count on form submission using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

How to properly get message count on form submission using reactjs.

For  hours now am on this trying to find the possible solution.

The Application below submits and displays message info and everything works fine.
Now I have task of implementing a message counter  each time message is submitted by a user.

**This is what I have done to implement counter for the user**

```
var senderId ='Nancy101';
const {textCount} = this.state;
var count = textCount[senderId] == undefined ? 1 : textCount[senderId] + 1;
textCount[senderId] = count;

alert('am counting: ' +count);
```

**Here is my issue after adding the textcount method above**

Each time I submit the form am having error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Nancy101' of undefined

at bundle.js:109988
```

here is the line of code that causes the issue

```
var count = textCount[senderId] == undefined ? 1 : textCount[senderId] + 1;
```

**Here is the code**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";


class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
message: '',
    };

 this.sendMessage = this.sendMessage.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
  var textCount = [];
  }




 sendMessage = (message_text) => {

 alert(message_text);


 this.setState({

      data: [
        { id: "1", name: "Nancy101", message: "Hello from User1"}
      ]
    });



        }

  render() {

    return (

          <div>


                                 <input type="text"  placeholder="Message" value={this.state.message} onChange={ev => this.setState({message: ev.target.value})}/>
                                <br/>
                                <span onClick={ () => this.sendMessage(this.state.message)}>Submit</span>

{this.state.data.map((message, i) => {

if (message.message !=='' && message.name !=='') {

//var senderId=message.name;
var senderId ='Nancy101';
const {textCount} = this.state;
var count = textCount[senderId] == undefined ? 1 : textCount[senderId] + 1;
textCount[senderId] = count;

alert('am counting: ' +count);



          return (
            <div key={i}>
       <div>   
 {message.name}: {message.message}
            </div>
              </div>
          )


  } else {

//alert nothing.


  }
        })}



          </div>

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is happening because you trying to get `textCount`from `state`. However, your state doesn't have a key named `textCount`.

This is what you are doing.

```
const { textCount } = this.state;
```

It's mean this.

```
const textCount = this.state.textCount;
```

Which is return you an undefined because your state object doesn't have that key.

Then you are trying to get the value of the key named `Nancy101` from `undefined` object that's why you get that error.

You can fix it by add `textCount` in your initial state inside constructor like this.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: [],
        message: '',
        textCount: {},
    };
```

Instead of get undefined here `const {textCount} = this.state;`, now you got an object. `{}`

Also, you can update this line.

```
`var count = textCount[senderId] == undefined ? 1 : textCount[senderId] + 1;`
```

To this.

```
`let count = !textCount[senderId] ? 1 : textCount[senderId] + 1;`
```

with this `!textCount[senderId]` it gonna check your data that is it equal `0`, `undefined` or `''`.

Comment: Thanks Sir Natsathorn